# Split 3 dimensional Array in multiple 2 dimensional Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

In Java you can do:

```
int [][][] a = new int[2][10][10];
int [][] b = a[0];
```

But in c# you can't do:

```
int [,,] a = new int[2,10,10];
int [,] b = a[0];
```

How would I do this in c#.
I just know that I can do this if I want to get a row:

```
int[,] a = new int[2,10];
int[] b = a.GetRow(0);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Poul Bak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741643/poul-bak), you can use [jagged arrays](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-jagged-arrays/) in *C#* as follows:

```
int[][][] arr = new int[2][][];

for (int row = 0; row < arr.Length; row++)
{
    arr[row] = new int[10][];

    for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].Length; col++)
    {
        arr[row][col] = new int[10];
    }
}

for (int row = 0; row < arr.Length; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].Length; col++)
        for (int plane = 0; plane < arr[row][col].Length; plane++)
            arr[row][col][plane] = row*100 + col*10 + plane;

int[][] b = arr[1];

for (int col = 0; col < b.Length; col++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int plane = 0; plane < b[col].Length; plane++)
        Console.Write($" {b[col][plane],3}");
}
```